# Node analysis: estimating variable current branches

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, schematics, kirchhoffs-laws, nodal-analysis

Is there a way to get the number of potential currents that could be in a circuit? (Note: in the following circuits ignore the Resistor value, I've just added a resistor with the default schematic value, but pretend that each resistor might have a different value).

For example, in the following circuit, there would be one:

[image]

In this circuit there would be two (ignoring R1=R2):

[image]

And in this circuit there would be 7:

[image]

My initial thought was the formula would be:

- +1 current for each connection from the Voltage source
- (+) number of outgoing connections for each connection point where it has either >1 incoming connections or >1 outgoing connections (ignore ground). Another way to put it is degree at the node > 3

Is that correct, or is there a better/simpler way to find the number of potential current sources?

Comment: how do you get 7 in the third circuit?

Comment: @jsotola see updated question please with labels for the third picture.

Comment: I3 and I7 are the same current

Comment: @jsotola of course, and in the second graph there's only two currents (not three). But my question here is more to ignore the resistance values. For example, if I changed I7 resistor(s) to be 1 ohm instead of 1000 they would have different currents.

Comment: @David542 No, I3 and I7 would still be the same current. They have to be. Don't you see why?

Comment: @jonk -- oh, I see. With current flowing in = current flowing out. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What you really want to know asking this question?

Comment: In computer nodal analysis, I7 will actually be two currents. The current through the first 1 kohm resistor, and the current through the second 1 kohm resistor. There will be an equation in the system saying these currents are equal, but as far as setting up the equations, they will be treated as distinct variables.

Answer (score 0):

The nodal equations will be `(N-1)` for a circuit with `N` number of nodes.   Hence, the `N-1` will be the number of variables (currents).

If you can find the number of nodes, you will be able to find number of currents you are requested to solve.

To solve, there will be still challenges for example:  when there are dependent sources

Comment: thanks for this. When you say "Nodes" do you mean electrical components (non-wires?) or could you please clarify? Also, would 'ground' be a component? If not, then would the answer be 8 for the last circuit I've included? Finally, for the first circuit that would mean 2 currents? (both identical)

Comment: Nodes are the points where two or more circuit elements meet. The wires are normally ignored (zero resistance, zero parasitics). Sometimes you may have to solve the circuit before starting counting the nodes

Comment: so that would mean 3-1=2 currents? But I already see four currents in that existing graphic.

Comment: You have to choose a point as reference. Here it is ground node which you are missing. It will be 4 in total